# Counterexample Immersed Submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ be a manifold.

> Let $N$ be a subset of $M$ and suppose that $N$ is endowed with a manifold structure for which the inclusion $i: N \rightarrow M$ is a smooth map. Is $N$ necessarily an immersed submanifold of $M$?

My definition of an immersed submanifold is the following: an immersed submanifold of $M$ is a subset $H \subset M$ with a topology and a smooth manifold structure such that the inclusion $i: H \rightarrow M$ is an immersion.

Looking at the definition of an immersed submanifold, it looks clear to me that the statement is not true since the derivative of the inclusion at every point has to be injective. However, I can't come up with a counterexample. Furthermore, I have trouble to find examples of inclusions whose derivative at a point is not injective. Someone who can given me a clear example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be worth starting studying the critical points of a smooth function. AS you probably know, if $f:M\to N$ is a smooth function and $f$ is a summersion at $p\in M$, then $f^{-1}(p)$ is a submanifold of $M$. See what happens at critical points. I was thinking about the map $\{(x,y)\mapsto x^3-y^2\}$. The pre-image of zero under this map looks smooth, but because the way it's been regarded as a submanifold, it might not be an immersed submanifold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $M = \mathbb R^2$ and $N = \{ (x, 0)\in M|\  x\in \mathbb R\}$ be the x axis. Then $\{(N, \varphi)\}$ with $\varphi : N\to \mathbb R$, $\varphi (x, 0) = x^{1/3}$ is a smooth atlas on $N$. Let $\iota : N \to M$ be the inclusion, then under the local chart $(N, \varphi)$ and $(\mathbb R^2, \mathrm{id})$ on $M = \mathbb R^2$,

$$ \mathrm{id}_M \circ \iota \circ\varphi^{-1} (t) = (t^3, 0).$$
Thus $\iota$ is smooth but not immersed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why it is the case that the derivative of the inclusion is not injective? Sorry for the late reply, but I thought I had it but made some stupid error which I realized now.

Comment: My definition of a tangent vector is an equivalence class of smooth curves $\gamma: (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow M$ with $\gamma(0) = p$ where $\gamma_1 \sim \gamma_2 \iff$ there exists a chart $(U,\phi)$ such that $(\phi\circ \gamma_1)'(0) = (\phi\circ\gamma_2)'(0)$. With some bad notation, but hopefully understandable, this gives with your counterexample the following, that $[i\circ\gamma_1] = [i\circ\gamma_2]$ implies that $\gamma_1'(0) = \gamma_2'(0)$. We must have then that $[\gamma_1] \neq [\gamma_2]$. But working this out with your specific chart gives [...]

Comment: [...] $1/3 \gamma_1^{-2/3}(0) \gamma_1'(0) = 1/3 \gamma_2^{-2/3}(0) \gamma_2'(0)$, which is always true since  $\gamma_1(0) = \gamma_2(0)$ and the hypothesis.

Comment: Let $\gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to N$ be $\gamma (t) = (t^3, 0)$. Then $\varphi \circ \gamma (t) = t$, thus $[\gamma]$ corresponds to a non-zero tangent vector. But $d\iota [\gamma] = [\iota\circ \gamma]$ and $(\iota\circ \gamma)'(0) = (0,0)$ is zero. Thus $d\iota$ maps a non-zero tangent vector $[\gamma]$ to the zero vector, and so $d\iota$ is not injective. @Kabouter9

Answer (score 1):

Here's another easy example, taken from Loring Tu's very readable book "An Introduction to Manifolds": take $N=(\mathbb R,\text{id})\ M=(\mathbb R^2,\text{id})$ and $f: t\mapsto (t^2,t^3).$ Then, $f$ is injective, but $f'(0):T_0\mathbb R\to T_0\mathbb R^2$ is the zero linear transformation. The graph illustrates the "problem."

[image]

Comment: To be precise, your $f$ is not the inclusion map, and if framed correctly, your example is almost the same as mine: On $N$ you define the chart $(N, \varphi) $ with $\varphi (t^2, t^3) =t$. Then it gives an smooth structure on $N$ and the the inclusion $\iota : N \to \mathbb R^2$ has $f = \iota \circ \varphi^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Tu's example does not apply as written here.