# Smooth atlas and $C^\infty$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

May be this is a stupid question but in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4338398, it is said that $\varphi(x,0)=x^\frac{1}{3}$ is a smooth atlas on $N=\{(x,0)\in \mathbb R^2 | x \in \mathbb R \}$ but, shouldn't $\varphi(x,0)$ be $C^\infty$ to be a smooth atlas?

ps. I couldn't "Add a comment" in that question, that's the reason I'm posting it here (I don't know if this is an appropriate procedure, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoothness of $\varphi$ as a map from the manifold $N$ to $\mathbb{R}$ depends on what smooth structure you put on $N$.

The $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism from $N$ to $\mathbb{R}$ so you directly define the smooth structure on $N$ to be consisting of the chart $(N,\varphi)$ and hence you get smoothness. That is you are simply declaring that this $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism and thus giving $N$ the topology and smooth structure induced by this map.

Comment: But $\varphi(x,0) = x^{1/3}$ is not a diffeomorphism between $N$ and $\mathbb R$

Comment: Do you yet know the smooth structure on $N$? . As I said, the smoothness depends on the smooth strucutre on $N$. Stop trying to view it as a map from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. You do not yet have a smooth structure on $N$. But since you have a homeomorphism you can define the smooth structure on $N$ to be induced by this map which we are declaring to be a diffeomorphism. That is the entire point of the example

Comment: For example this map $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism. So I can create a smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$ by taking this to be my Global chart and it will give me a unique smooth maximal atlas. Obviously it does not coincide with our usual notion of smoothness . Put more explicitly, $N$ is not even an open set. You are viewing the $x$ axis embedded in $\Bbb{R^{2}}$ as a manifold in it's own right and you are giving it a smooth structure induced by this homeomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You mean that "by definition" any homeomorphism from $N$ to $\mathbb R$ is also a diffeomorphism in the chart that it defines?

Comment: What is the definition of smooth structure?, to put it vaguely, it is just a collection of open sets and homeomorphisms. A diffeomorphsim from $M\to N$ is such that given charts $\phi,\psi$ you have $\psi\circ F\phi^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism from the respective domain and range in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ . This is called the coordinate representation. And if you define the charts to be consisting of just one homeomorphism, then the coordinate representation would just become identity which is smooth.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I think I understand. You say that the coordinate representation of a chart $\varphi : M \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, if it makes any sense seeing it as a map from $M$ to $\mathbb R^n$ (using the identity as the chart of $\mathbb R^n$), is always the identity because this coordinate representation would be trivially given by, $id\circ \varphi\circ\varphi^{-1}:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, which is of course smooth (although probably not very useful). Ok, Many thanks!

Comment: Exactly.....It's what you would call bad coordinates....or atleast non-standard coordinates. Also you can mark as answer(any one of them) to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to put it:

Suppose $N$ is a set (no other assumptions) for which there is a bijection $\phi_0: N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. You can now define an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ consisting of all bijections $\phi: N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi\circ\phi_0^{-1}: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is smooth. In this example, let $N$ be the real line and $\phi_0: N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $\phi_0(x) = x^{1/3}$. This turns $N$ into a smooth $1$-dimensional manifold.

You now have two different manifold structures on $N$, one using this atlas and one using the standard atlas. The identity map from $N$ as a manifold using the first atlas to $N$ as a manifold using the second atlas is not a diffeomorphism. The two manifold structures are in fact diffeomorphic. It's not too hard, using the atlases, to find a diffeomorphism.

Comment: But then, these two incompatible charts do not belong to the same complete atlas? I mean, we can define them many different complete atlases in, for example, this manifold and any of these atlases defines a smooth structure on $N$ so that a function, for instance, can be differentiable in one atlas but not differentiable in another atlas?

Comment: Two different atlases on the same set do not need to be compatible. If you have a set $M$ with two atlases $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$, then there is no requirement that if $\phi_1 \in \mathcal{A}_1$ and $\phi_2\in\mathcal{A}_2$, that $\phi_2\circ\phi_1^{-1}$ be smooth. An atlas has to be self-consistent but does not need to be consistent with a different atlas. You should think of the set underlying a manifold as just a set. No topology, nothing. It's only when you choose an atlas does the set become a manifold.

Comment: For example, all the standard definitions of a manifold start with the assumption that $M$ is a topological space. This assumption is in fact unnecessary, because the atlas itself uniquely determines the topology of the manifold (i.e., which subsets are open).

Comment: And, yes, a function can be differentiable with respect to one atlas but not with respect to another atlas.

Comment: Ok, I see it perfectly clear now. Thank you very much! If I may, let me ask you one more question. Does this have something to do with the fact that some functions, eg. a metric, can be pathological in one coordinate system but not in another? Is that what is usually called "a bad choice of coordinates"?

Comment: @Salvador , Deane's comment is absolutely correct. In fact that is the reason why we define a "Maximal Smooth Atlas". Also you can look at the definition of smoothness of a map $F:M\to N$ . It is smooth if for charts $\phi,psi$ for $M$ and $N$, the map $\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1}$ is smooth as a map from $\Bbb{R^{m}\to R^{n}}$ . Now guess what such a definition of smoothness does to the map $\sqrt[3]{x}$?.

Comment: @Salvador, both of your comments are correct.